# Verifying Back-End Calls from Android Apps with OpenID Connect

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-openid

Based on [this blog article](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) I managed to validate a Android App client token for a Google account on the back-end side, using the Google OAuth2 API and the example Checker class in the article.

I noticed that [GoogleIdToken.Payload#getIssuee()](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdToken.Payload.html#getIssuee()) is deprecated. The JavaDoc explains that this method is

> "scheduled to be removed in 1.18, use
>   [IdToken.Payload.getAuthorizedParty()](http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/auth/openidconnect/IdToken.Payload.html?is-external=true#getAuthorizedParty%28%29) instead."

The IdToken class uses OpenID Connect instead of OAuth 2.0, which modifications do I need to apply to the example Checker class to use OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 0):

No changes are required: OpenID Connect is an extension of OAuth 2.0; you can just change your code to:

```
if (mVerifier.verify(token)) {
    GoogleIdToken.Payload tempPayload = token.getPayload();
    if (!tempPayload.getAudience().equals(mAudience))
        mProblem = "Audience mismatch";
    else if (!mClientIDs.contains(tempPayload.getAuthorizedParty()))
        mProblem = "Client ID mismatch";
    else
        payload = tempPayload;
}
```

The implementation of the getIssuee method already uses that very same call:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdToken.java

What happened is that Google already implemented the relevant bits of OpenID Connect avant la lettre in the GoogleIdToken class that was part of their OAuth 2.0 implementation. In the long run it may be better to use the standard (non-Google-specific) OpenID Connect classes that Google has added since then:
https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/google-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/#client%2Fauth%2Fopenidconnect%253Fstate%253Dclosed
but that becomes urgent only when the whole class is marked as deprecated.